# How to get a html element to overlap another when it is displayed?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, program-entry-point, overlap

```
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    font-color: blue;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

[image: Current output]
For example, I have a mobile responsive site, and the main menu works fine, but when I resize the browser window to be small, to replicate a small screen such  as a mobile phones.... One of the main menu items that has a drop down list gets displayed on top of the other main menu items. This means that the main menu drop down items are displayed on top of some main menu text directly underneath!

I have done z index so the drop down menu does sit on top, but the problem is, even though it sits on top, the main menu underneath is still displayed.

This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjfff0r4/)

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: Agreed, show code. But I imagine you don't have a background colour on your menu. Even a bg of white will hide the stuff underneath and only show your menu text/content.

Comment: So they are overlapping but you don't want them to be? I don't understand your goal. It sounds like you have CSS positioning that you don't want.

Comment: @AshleyYoung Please [edit] your question and put the code there in a code block. (Indent 4 spaces for a code block). Important code doesn't belong in the comments.

Comment: }

#nav ul ul li:hover {

display: block;
font-color: blue;
font-size: 1.5em;
z-index: 99;
position: relative;




}

Comment: #nav_wrapper {

width: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
position: relative;


}


#nav ul {

list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 0.6em;
text-align: center;
font-color: black;



}

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @4castle they are overlapping and i want them to overlap.......BUT i want the overlapping element to hise the underlying element it is overlapping! see my pic attached

Comment: @AshleyYoung The picture is good, but please [edit] to put your code in the question. You need to have a [mcve]

Comment: @4castle i have tried over 5 times now

Comment: #nav ul ul li {

display: block;
font-color: blue;
font-size: 1.5em;
z-index: 1;
position: relative;

Comment: Under your post and the tags you added you find the "edit" button. Please but the code there (and format it correctly).

Comment: what code exactly do you want? this part? #nav ul ul li {

display: block;
font-color: blue;
font-size: 1.5em;
z-index: 1;
position: relative;

}

Comment: thanks guys, thanks

Comment: Okay, sorry to give you the runaround, but if you make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) that shows the problem, I'd be happy to edit it into the question. We need HTML and CSS

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jjfff0r4/

Comment: Can you see the code now?

Comment: I understand your frustration, I have tried to edit your post to help you out... but please do not put comments like the one above they surely will not help you to get answers (delete it). To ping a user that have commented on your post you need to use @username (otherwise they will not see it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't set `z-index`, elements follow a default ordering for which gets displayed on top:

> > When no element has a z-index, elements are stacked in this order (from bottom to top):
> >
> > 1. Background and borders of the root element
> > 2. Descendant blocks in the normal flow, in order of appearance (in HTML)
> > 3. Descendant positioned elements, in order of appearance (in HTML)
>
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index)

In your HTML, the `ul` for the submenu appears before the HTML for the other menu items, and so the other menu items appear on top of the submenu's background.

To fix this, set a `z-index` so that the background of the `ul` will be promoted:

```css
#nav ul ul {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[Fixed JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjfff0r4/1/)

Comment: YOU ARE THE KING !

Comment: @AshleyYoung Lol, thanks. In the future though, let's try to make this a smoother process. That was a bit of a dramatic rollercoaster, and I or someone else could have answered sooner if we had the full code from the start. Thanks for working with us though.